# How to add "onClick" to multiple buttons generated by Javascript and written to InnerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a list of users. For each row I want to add the avatar, name and a button to open a modal with the user's profile. I am having trouble adding the "onClick"s to each button.

Ive searched and found multiple solutions that would require me to rewrite this whole function. I was wondering if there was a way to solve this and still get to keep the way I am implementing the ul's.

It is worth to mention that I am not using JQuery.

Here is the code:

```js
const userList = document.querySelector('.userListDiv');

const setupUserList = (data, currentUser) => {
  if(data.length) {
    let html = '';
    var list = [];
    data.forEach(doc => {
      const user = doc.data();
      if(user.coachUid == currentUser.uid)
      {
        list.push(user);
      }
    });

    list.forEach(user => {
      const ul = `
        <ul class="userListUl pull-right" style="border-left: 0px;">
            <li>
                <button class="button" id="myBtn"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:48px;color:rgb(34, 34, 34)">person</i></button>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="userListUl" style="border-right: 0px;">
            <li>
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" class="userListImg" alt="Avatar">
            </li>
            <li>
                <p class="userListP">${user.personal_info[0]} ${user.personal_info[1]}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
      `;
      html += ul
    });

    userList.innerHTML = html;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="userListDiv logged-in"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Executing your snippet shows me a blank page. Read about `event.target`, event bubbling and *delegate listeners*. When you have done that you know how to address this common problem. Also make sure you **never** use the same `id` value for more than one element in the whole page. `id` must at all costs be unique.

Comment: You need to give us a way to execute the "users" -- Since you're importing them .. Throw an example object into your code ..

Comment: @JoaoBM what exactly is the issue you are facing ? You can add onclick event handlers inside your template string also.

Comment: You have all of your buttons using the same id: `myBtn`. Do not do that.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur Which would be **very bad practice**.

Comment: @connexo Indeed but I want to know what the author did that went wrong because it's still doable. One can always address more info regarding practices in the answer.

Comment: Apologies. The block of code was only meant to be shown. Not to be run. I will start reading on event bubbling and delegate listeners and update my answer or provide a solution if I find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a snippet at the point you have added your HTML then you wont need to change any of your existing code? See comment/snippet below...

```
const userList = document.querySelector('.userListDiv');

const setupUserList = (data, currentUser) => {
  if (data.length) {
    let html = '';
    const list = [];
    data.forEach(doc => {
      const user = doc.data();
      if (user.coachUid == currentUser.uid) {
        list.push(user);
      }
    });

    list.forEach(user => {
      const ul = `
        <ul class="userListUl pull-right" style="border-left: 0px;">
          <li>
            <button class="button"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:48px;color:rgb(34, 34, 34)">person</i></button>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="userListUl" style="border-right: 0px;">
          <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" class="userListImg" alt="Avatar">
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="userListP">${user.personal_info[0]} ${user.personal_info[1]}</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      `;
      html += ul
    });

    userList.innerHTML = html;

    // Add event listener to buttons.
    const buttons = userList.querySelectorAll('.userListUl .button');
    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert('Button clicked!');
      });
    }
  }
}
```